# Grant access to Windows 7 PC to other computer users

Tags: windows-7, permissions, network-shares, trust

A Windows 7 Professional computer, is connected to a network, however when specifying security settings to local resources (such as files & folders sharing, grant access to SQL server, etc) using the following dialog

[image: Users dialog]

it is impossible to list users from other computers. Where should I enable (grant?) access to other computer/users in a way the can be listed and allowed to access local resources?

Comment: Is AIACE the computer, or a Domain name?

Comment: Do you have file sharing enabled on your system?

Comment: AIACE is a sample computer name. File sharing is enabled. With the dialog above, only local users are visible; other computer are not listed at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are not using a domain.

In which case, you won't have common objects between the two machines like you would on a windows domain.

In the past using Workgroups,  I would set up identical user accounts (same username, same password) on both/all machines.  Windows, when connecting to a remote machine, will attempt to authenticate with it's current credentials.  Having matching credentials on the remote machine means it just 'works' under normal conditions.

However, with Windows 7 there is "Home Groups" which can somewhat simplify the sharing of files and printers between computers.  If all your machines are windows 7 or up, look in to using home groups to share resources around your network.

If you have a mixture of devices, you might be better off simply buying a cheap NAS box and pointing all your machines to that instead, or perhaps your router has a USB port that can share an external USB hard drive for you without the cost of buying a dedicated NAS.

Comment: Using homegroups seems working. Thanks :-)